# Forwarding interfaces inside a docker container

Tags: networking, server, iptables, docker

I have created a docker container executing the following command

```
docker run -it --net=none --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name firewall ubuntu /bin/bash
```

after I have attached it two interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`. I need to forward traffic from eth1 to eth0. I have installed `iptables` and applying the following simple rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

I have checked out that traffic arrive to interface eth1 by listening with tcpdump the interface eth1. Unfortunately I don't know the reason why the traffic is not forwarded to eth0. Any idea? All the flags have been properly set up to 1 on the system

Comment: I think we need more information. I suspect that iptables doesn't know the packets should route to the FORWARD chain, and therefore they end up in the INPUT chain. You can check via observing the counters for "sudo iptables -v -x -n -L" . What are the addresses of eth1 and eth0 and what is the destination of the packets arriving at eth1?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I need to forward traffic from eth1 to eth0", because maybe you need the `route` command to route IP from `eth0` to `eth1`.

Comment: Fabby I have to forward incoming packets (having external ip addresses) coming in from eth1 (192.168.33.x) to eth0 (10.0.2.25)

Comment: So, you are missing some iptables rules, but we'll get to that later. You need to decide where you want the packets to go (after they go out from eth0), because you need to translate the destination IP address. And you need to detail what ports you want to forward.

Comment: after they go out from eth0 they arrive to a switch then it would be the switch to take care of them. yes I agree with you when you say the packets need to be translated. I haven't thought about this yet because normally the eth0 should get the packets from eth1 although the address is not correct. ping and http port are good enough at the moment

Comment: You have not defined what you want with enough clarity such that the question can be answered. An incoming port 80 packet to 162.168.33.x should be forwarded to where on the 10.0.2.0 sub-net? (where I just assumed a netmask of 255.255.255.0, which might be wrong.) And please do not say "a switch". OR are you trying to implement a router where an incoming packet would actually be in reply to a packet originally sent by something on the 10.0.2.0 sub-net?

Comment: yes. an incoming packet 80 from eth0 with source address 192.168.33.x has to be forwarded to 10.0.2.x network. The eth1 is connected to a linux bridge that is in host machine. This forwarding takes place in a docker container.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example iptables rule set script for my guess as to what you need / want. I have guessed at some addresses, you will have to edit for what you really need.

```
#!/bin/sh
FWVER=0.01
#
# Mazzy Example 2015.02.20 Ver:0.01
#     Only port 80.

echo "Loading Mazzy Example iptables rules set. version $FWVER..\n"

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
#
EXTIF="eth0"
INTIF="eth1"
# For example: Please replace with real IP address
EXTIP="192.168.33.134"
INTNET="10.0.2.0/24"
INTIP="10.0.2.25"
# For example: Please replace with real desintation IP address
INT80="10.0.2.43"
UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

echo "   External Interface: $EXTIF   Internal Interface: $INTIF   External IP: $EXTIP  Internal Network: $INTNET   Internal IP: $INTIP"

# Only needed if not already done elesewhere
#CRITICAL:  Enable IP forwarding since it is disabled by default
#
echo Enabling forwarding...
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policy to DROP.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD DROP
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z
# Smythies: While my references do not have it, I think this is needed.
$IPTABLES -t nat -Z

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# At this point local interface, local machines, going anywhere is valid
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $INTIF -s $INTNET -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# loopback interface is valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

# any source going to local net is valid
#
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o $INTIF -s $EXTIP -d $INTNET -j ACCEPT

# server source going to the local net is valid
#
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o $INTIF -s $INTIP -d $INTNET -j ACCEPT

# anything else outgoing on remote interface is valid
#
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o $EXTIF -s $EXTIP -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT

echo Loading FORWARD rulesets...
echo "FWD: Allow all connections OUT and only existing/related IN..."
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# port forward stuff. see also the prerouting area.
#
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -p tcp --dport 80 -d $INT80 -m state --state NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "PFNEW80:" --log-level info
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $EXTIF -o $INTIF -p tcp --dport 80 -d $INT80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
#
$IPTABLES -A FORWARD -i $INTIF -o $EXTIF -j ACCEPT

# some port forward stuff. (normally commented out) see also FORWARD area.
#
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i $EXTIF --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $INT80:80

echo "NAT: Enabling SNAT (MASQUERADE) functionality on $EXTIF..."
#
#More liberal form
#$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j MASQUERADE
#
#Stricter form
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $EXTIF -j SNAT --to $EXTIP

echo Mazzy Example iptables rules set. $FWVER done.
```